# Form for HABTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, simple-form, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, Album and Image. These have has_and_belongs_to associations with eachother. An album has many images, and an image can belong to many albums. Is it correct to specify HABTM then?

After I create an album, it redirects to the album show path. On this page, I would like to allow the user to add (upload) images to the album. However, I'm not sure how to specify the form for this. I'm using simpleform. I tried something like this (haml):

```
  = simple_form_for [:admin, @album] do |a|
    = a.simple_fields_for :images do |i| 
      = i.input :title
      = i.file_field :image
      = i.submit
```

But that just updates the album and doesn't create the image. I also got an error saying "Image expected, got Array".

I would like to allow my users to upload images directly on the album show page. It feels wrong to have a separate image upload page where they specify the album. Makes a huge difference in UX, in my mind.

Or.. I guess I could have a link saying 'add image' and when clicked, render a partial, say `image/_upload_form` in a modal? That's a backup plan however. Looking for a solution for the image form on the album show page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `submit` the `form`,not the `fields`.

This code

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @album] do |a|
    = a.simple_fields_for :images do |i| 
      = i.input :title
      = i.file_field :image
      = i.submit
```

should be

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @album] do |a|
    = a.simple_fields_for :images do |i| 
      = i.input :title
      = i.file_field :image
    = a.submit #Here
```

Comment: @Mandeep Yeah,just about to edit,then i saw your edit :)

Comment: This gives me an error: 'ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch', 'Image(#70146303479620) expected, got Array(#70146232389660)'.